# Glossary entry not displayed in list

Tags: glossaries

Is there any option to make a glossary entry not to appear in the glossaries list? I want it to be in the text and behave as glossary/acronym, but I don't want it to be displayed in the list index.

Thanks

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Which glossary package do you use?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I use glossaries package. It is really difficult to create a MWE as I only want to know if there is an option in the \newacronym command to set not to be displayed in the list.

Comment: Well, a short file with a acronym definition, such that other users do not have to create it for you...

Comment: I think, you should ask the author of the `glossaries` package, Nicola Talbot. She is also a user here and perhaps also available in TeX.SX chat. Just look around ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a minimal working example (MWE) that uses the method suggested in the section [Links to Glossary Entries](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:glslink) in the user manual:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,nohypertypes={common}]{glossaries}

\newglossary{common}{cacr}{cacn}{Common Acronyms}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a sample acronym}
\newacronym[type=common]{xyz}{XYZ}{another sample acronym}

\begin{document}

First use: \gls{abc}, \gls{xyz}, \gls{sample}.
Next use: \gls{abc}, \gls{xyz}.

\printglossary
\printglossary[type=acronym]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

**Update:**

As from version 4.08 you can defined an "ignored glossary" using `\newignoredglossary` instead of `\newglossary`. The above example can be rewritten:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newignoredglossary{common}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\newacronym{abc}{ABC}{a sample acronym}
\newacronym[type=common]{xyz}{XYZ}{another sample acronym}

\begin{document}

First use: \gls{abc}, \gls{xyz}, \gls{sample}.
Next use: \gls{abc}, \gls{xyz}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as the above image.